# The Ohr Hachaim's Moshiach Claim

Tags: messiah

After some discussion, someone brought up that the Ohr Hachaim (Rav Chaim Ben Attar) made a claim that he was the messiah.  If so, would anyone know where the Ohr Hachaim writes, regarding himself, that he was Moshiach?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think there is story on how the Ohr Hachaim and the Arizal or possibly the Baal Shem Tov didn’t meet in Israel otherwise they could have brought the Moshiach.

Comment: possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30144/170

Comment: The ohr hachaim does write that he expects moshiach to come in his time. 1696-43. Must be at the end of his life. That the jewish year 5500 would be the start of the moshiach era. Because 1000 years is 24 hours of hashem. So the last day starts at 5500.

Comment: Love all the comments this question brought, but not a single upvote :)

Comment: @TheThinkingYid Please remind what the upvotes do.

Comment: @DanielRoss It gives him reputation, and in turn certain editing and other privileges. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour. (And Thinking Yid, sorry for overlooking that previously! Thanks for the reminder.)

Comment: @meir thanks a ton! Not sure why people forget!

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer brought by the BaisMoshiach.org. http://www.beismoshiach.org/Moshiach/moshiach355b.htm

> The Ohr HaChaim believed that he was Moshiach. There’s a tremendous story told about the Ohr HaChaim HaKodesh, who had to reprint his book. The printer’s name was Asher. In the book, the Ohr HaChaim wrote clearly that the name of Moshiach is going to be Chaim. The printer happened to be a very simple person, and when he came across this statement, he felt it was pompous to make a statement like that, so he omitted the statement.

Comment: The way I heard the story, it's not that the printer was a "very simple person," but a maskil, who didn't really believe in Moshiach at all. The upshot, continues the story, is that his name, Asher, ended up being inadvertently (mis)printed in the expression אמן מאיש אחר in connection with the Sotah, and eventually it was discovered that in fact he was guilty of adultery. That version is [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=24647#p=162).

Comment: With that said, in a discussion on Chareidim Ladaas (https://chl.co.il/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13468&start=50), some posters cite opinions that with that phrase the Ohr Hachaim was actually referring to his namesake, R. Chaim Abulafia, rather than to himself.

Comment: Can anyone identify/link a copy of this alleged misprinted edition? How do we even know that a phrase was omitted?

Comment: @DoubleAA The first link I gave is actually to a bibliographical description of the edition (the writer, R. Chaim Liberman, was a rather careful bibliographer). Whether a scan of it is available online, I don't know.

Comment: @DoubleAA Also, a variant version of the story is quoted in [Dvar Yom Beyomo, 10 Elul](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=31168#p=224&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), and the author, R' Chaim Knoller, writes that he saw a copy of these chumashim with both of these, the deleted ושמו חיים and the mistaken מאשר.

Comment: How do you see a deleted ושמו חיים?? I can see hundreds of them in every comment!

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm assuming you're joking. What it means is that you don't see it _where it's supposed to be_ - that, knowing (from other printings) that the Ohr Hachaim's commentary on that verse is supposed to end with the words משיח ה' ושמו חיים, you find that it just ends with 'משיח ה and the last two words are missing.

Comment: How do we know it from other printings if this is the first edition that R Chaim actually was there? Do we have the original manuscript? That would be a possibility I suppose

Comment: Not sure how this is an answer...

Comment: @DoubleAA Because it wasn't the first printing, and the Ohr Hachaim had passed away over forty years earlier (in 1743; this was in 1785). The first printing was actually during the OH's lifetime, and indeed it has שמו חיים (https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=14148#p=317, about the middle of the left column - actually, in that printing it looks like it says שמי, in first person!). Another edition, a few years after the mutilated one we're discussing, has it too (https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=38296#p=36, top of the second column).

Comment: (Note that based on that, the claim in the story - that the Ohr Hachaim "had to reprint his book" - is incorrect. The first version of the story I linked distinctly states that the OH found out about the mutilation "in Gan Eden.")

Comment: @TheThinkingYid The answer is sort of buried, but the meat of it is that in his commentary to Devarim 15:7 the Ohr Hachaim writes of Moshiach, "His name is Chaim," and a popular understanding is that he was referring to himself.